# Extracting Substrings from a List in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, substring

If I have a parent string (let's call it `output`) that contains a list of variable assignments like so ...

```
status.availability-state available
status.enabled-state enabled
status.status-reason The pool is available
```

And I want to extract the values of each variable in that list given the variable names, ie the substring after the space following `status.availability-state`, `status.enabled-state`, and `status.status-reason`, such that I end up with three different variable assignments making each of the following String comparisons true ...

```
String availability = output.substring(TODO);
String enabled = output.substring(TODO);
String reason = output.substring(TODO);

availability.equals("available");
enabled.equals("enabled");
reason.equals("The pool is available");
```

What is the simplest way to do this?  Should I even use `substring` for this?

Comment: do you use those as preset properties ?

Comment: If you know the sequence of the properties appear you can separe by a ',' (comma) for example, and do a String.split(",") to create an array of strings.

Comment: @JohnnyWiller I'd like to be able to do it without necessarily knowing the sequence, only given the variable name like `status.availability-state`

Comment: Is the list actually a `List<String>`, or just a single `String`, that separates the items via linebreak? ie. `String x = "line 1\r\nline 2";`

Comment: the property names on the left are really inconsistent for what you want as well. If you cant change that then there is no easy way around that.

Comment: @Zymus It's a single string with line breaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A valid alternative is to split the string by `\n` and add to a `Map`. Example:

```
String properties = "status.availability-state available\nstatus.enabled-state enabled\nstatus.status-reason The pool is available";

Map<String, String> map = Arrays.stream(properties.split("\n"))
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s.split(" ")[0], s -> s.split(" ", 2)[1]));

System.out.println(map.get("status.status-reason"));
```

Should output `The pool is available`

Comment: Nice simple one-liner.  I like it.

Comment: I like it too. Lambdas are elegant. But to @user2150250 - do you really think it's simple? I imagined that given the basic nature of the question, streams and lambdas would be too advanced a solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is a little tricky because you need to assign the value to a specific variable - you can't just have a map of keys to variables in Java.

I would consider doing this with a switch:

```
for (String line : output.split('\n')) {
  String[] frags = line.split(' ', 2);  // Split the line in 2 at the space.
  switch (frags[0]) {  // This is the "key" of the variable.
    case "status.availability-state":
      availability = frags[1];  // This assigns the "value" to the relevant variable.
      break;
    case "status.enabled-state":
      enabled = frags[1];
      break;
    // ... etc
  }
}
```

It's not very pretty, but you don't have too many options.

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be two questions here -- how to parse the string, and how to assign to variables by name.

Tackle the string parsing one step at a time:

- first write a program to read one line at a time and output each one in the body of a loop. `String.split()` or `StringTokenizer` are two options here.
- next enhance this by writing a method to handle one line. The same tools are helpful here, to split on spaces.
- You should now have a program that can print `name: status.availability-state, value: available` for each line of input.

Next, you're asking to programatically assign to variables based on the name of the parameter.

There is no legitimate way to look at a variable's name at runtime (OK, Java 8 reflection has ways, but it shouldn't be used without very good reason).

So, the best you can do is to use a `switch` or `if` statement:

```
switch(name) {
    case status.availability-state:
        availability = value;
        break;
    ... etc.
}
```

However, whenever you use `switch` or `if` you should think about whether there's a better way.

Is there any reason you can't turn these variables into `Map` entries?

```
 configMap.add(name,value);
```

Then to read it:

```
 doSomethingWith(configMap.get("status.availability");
```

That's what maps are for. Use them.

This is a similar situation to the rookie mistake of using variables called `person1`, `person2`, `person3`... instead of using an array. Eventually they ask "How do I go from the number 25 to my variable `person25`?" -- and the answer is, you can't, but an array or list makes it easy. `people[number]` or `people.get(number)`

Answer (score 0):

This loop will match and extract the variables, and you can then assign them as you see fit:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("status\\.(.*?)-.*? ([a-z]+)");
Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(output);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + "=" + matcher.group(2));
}
```

`status\\.` matches "status."

`(.*?)` matches any sequence of characters but isn't greedy, and captures them

`-.*` matches dash, any chars, space

`([a-z]+)` matches any string of lower-case letters, and captures them

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
Map<String, String> properties = getProperties(propertiesString);

availability = properties.get("availability-state");
enabled = properties.get("enabled-state");
reason = properties.get("status-reason");

// ...

public void getProperties(String input) {
    Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
    String[] lines = output.split("\n");

    for (String line : lines) {
        String[] parts = line.split(" ");
        int keyStartIndex = parts[0].indexOf(".") + 1;
        int spaceIndex = parts[1].indexOf(" ");
        string key = parts[0].substring(keyStartIndex, spaceIndex);
        properties.put(key, parts[1]);
    }

    return properties;
}
```

This seems to be a bit more straight-forward, in terms of the code that's setting these values, as each value is set to exactly the value from the map, rather than iterating over some list of strings and seeing if it contains a particular value and doing different things based on that.

This is designed with the primary use-case being that the string is created at runtime in memory. If the properties are created in an external file, this code would still work (after creating the desired String in memory), but it may be a better idea to use either a `Properties` file, or perhaps a `Scanner`.